# How can I support delta/partial updates to a Vaadin7 CustomLayout

Tags: java, vaadin, updates, vaadin7, partial

I have a complex layout which contains different components. Depending on some selections, the arrangement of these components in the layout changes.

I have used CustomLayout to paint these components and whenever I have some layout altering selection, I create a new CustomLayout and replace the old layout with new layout. This repaints only this whole layout on the browser.

I had to do this as Vaadin CustomLayout doesn't allow updates.

However, in many situations only minimal part of layout is changing.

1. How can we perform a delta update?
2. Is there any add-on which does something like this?
3. Can we patch Vaadin7 to handle delta update?

Comment: I think you have to split up your `customLayout` in separate custom layouts.